# Problem weight on different configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

We have 1 configurable product (Product A) related with 2 simple products (A1 and A2). Product A1 weights 120gr, Product A2 weights 150gr.

On the product page of Product A, there is a drop down menu to choose which product version you want to buy. So you can choose A1 or A2.

When you choose A1 or A2 the price on the page changes, but the weight no, even though the weight is different. 
How can we make the weight also to change depending on which product one chooses?

Thanks.